# sum of first value in nested list

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension, nested-lists

In traditional python, the `sum` function gives the sum of a `list`:

```
sum([0,1,2,3,4])=10
```

On the other hand, what if you have a nested list as so:

```
sum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

We find the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

In addition to this, how could we find the `sum` of the first values (index 0) in a nested list? Such as:

```
something([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])=12
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the sum of all the first elements you need to have a generator expression

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> sum(i[0] for i in a)
12
```

You are getting `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'` because you are trying to add the three lists which is not the desired behavior.

If you want a list of first elements and then find their sum, you can try a list comprehension instead

```
>>> l = [i[0] for i in a]
>>> l
[1, 4, 7]
>>> sum(l)
12
```

Or you can call the `__next__` method as list is an iterable (If Py3)

```
>>> sum(zip(*a).__next__())
12
```

Answer (score 1):

OR you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) :

```
>>> l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> sum(zip(*l)[0])
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to find sum of nested lists:

```
def nested_sum(par):
    total = 0 
    for k in par:
        if isinstance(k, list):  # checks if `k` is a list
            total += nested_sum(k)
        else:
            total += k
    return total
```

*@Kasara and @Bhargav also have some neat answers , check them out!*

Answer (score 0):

For python beginners:

By normal `for` loop and use try and except to handle exception when bested list is empty.

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], []]
>>> result = 0
>>> for i in l:
...     try:result += i[0]
...     except IndexError:pass
... 
>>> result
12
>>>
```

Comment: Don't use the old-style `except IndexError, e`, it is only present for backwards compatibility in Python 2(and removed in Python 3), use: `except IndexError as e`. BTW as you're doing nothing with the exception you can simply do: `except IndexError`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes, thank you to review my code, Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x:x[0],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is easy with `numpy`:

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

In [18]: my_array = np.array(a)

In [19]: my_array[:,0].sum()
Out[19]: 12
```